# Network UDP logger with replay

Tags: windows, logging, udp

I need network logger utility with ability to replay the data it collected, for example, I will record incoming data on UDP port 1234 for 10 minutes, record it to file, then replay that data (with same timing) to some other address:port.

I feel that it should be posted here, since it concerns development, not admin-ing.

EDIT:

It has to run on windows, and it can be standalone process that will listen to UDP port exclusively, so it doesn't have to be 'sniffer'.

Comment: What OS are we talking about? Can your logger listen to that port, or is it in use by another process, thus requiring your logger to be in fact a network sniffer?

Comment: What does this have to do with *programming* ?

Comment: It has to do with programming alot, since I intend to use it as a testing tool.  I record network traffic once, then replay it as a test case.

Comment: I did create my own utility for that...  nothing I found was useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/). It should do what you want to do when used in conjuction with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: Since I didn't specify windows as an OS, there I have it.  I am running from cygwin as fast as I can, but if only option, will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer imported from a similar question on superuser.com (also part of StackExchange): [Replay UDP Packet Capture](https://superuser.com/questions/382264/replay-udp-packet-capture)

**BitTwist** (http://bittwist.sourceforge.net) should be able to do what you want.

> With Bit-Twist, you can now regenerate your captured traffic onto a live network! Packets are generated from tcpdump trace file (.pcap file). Bit-Twist also comes with a comprehensive trace file editor to allow you to change the contents of a trace file.

The "trace file editor" part is what you are most interested in here.

I think you need to transform in two passes: one to change the IP addresses, another to change the UDP port numbers. I believe you can do this in either order.

```
bittwiste -I original.pcap -O changedip.pcap -T ip -s IP1,IP3 -d IP2,IP4
bittwiste -I changedip.pcap -O changedipandport.pcap -T udp -s Port1,Port3 -d Port2,Port4
```

where you need to stick in the IP addresses and port numbers, eg

```
bittwiste -I original.pcap -O changedip.pcap -T ip -s 192.168.0.1,10.10.0.3 -d 192.168.0.2,10.10.0.4
bittwiste -I changedip.pcap -O changedipandport.pcap -T udp -s 12345,24680 -d 80,8080
```

If your original capture file only has the IPs and port numbers of your original machines, you can simplify this by not mentioning the old IPs and port numbers in the edit commands, eg

```
bittwiste -I original.pcap -O changedip.pcap -T ip -s 10.10.0.3 -d 10.10.0.4
bittwiste -I changedip.pcap -O changedipandport.pcap -T udp -s 24680 -d 8080
```

to generate packets from 10.10.0.3:24680 to 10.10.0.4:8080.

You should be able to play back the `changedipandport.pcap` file using **Colasoft Packet Player** (http://www.colasoft.com/packet_player) or the commandline **BitTwist** player, eg

```
bittwist -i 1 changedipandport.pcap
```

where the "1" here is device 1. Use `bittwist -d` to list the devices.

There are other nifty options with the BitTwist player that you can't do with the Colasoft Packet Player, notably by changing the speed of the packets sent by a multiplier (eg 5 times original speed or 0.1 times original speed).

I have successfully tested this method using **Wireshark** (http://www.wireshark.org) to capture OSC data (UDP packets) sent from TouchOSC on an i-device to my laptop (via WiFi) at port 8000, using **bittwiste** (the editor) to change destination IP address to my wired ethernet adapter address and the UDP port to 8001, then replaying using **bittwist** (the player) to a **Pure Data** (http://puredata.info) patch listening on port 8001.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would try to use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

> Wireshark is the world's foremost
>   network protocol analyzer. It lets you
>   capture and interactively browse the
>   traffic running on a computer network.
>   It is the de facto (and often de jure)
>   standard across many industries and
>   educational institutions.